# Erro IdentityConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Estou tentando implementar Identity em meu projeto porém meu IdentityConfig está dando vários erros.
Comecei a pouco tempo a mexer com Identity e estou me batendo um pouco.

[image: Primeiro erro]
[image: Segundo erro][image: Terceiro erro][image: Quarto erro]

**packages.config**

```
<package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.6" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" /> 
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: E quais são os erros?

Comment: Os erros são parecidos : The type or namespace name ' ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sim, mas não estamos olhando sua tela. Pode por favor editar sua pergunta e colocar cada erro nela?

Comment: Mais uma dúvida @CiganoMorrisonMendez vi alguns comentários que o certo seria utilizar 2 Context quando se trabalha com Identity, isso é correto ?

Comment: Só é correto se você usar bases separadas: uma para o seu sistema, uma para o esquema de usuários e permissões. Preciso agora que você edite sua pergunta com o conteúdo do arquivo `packages.config`. Procure não usar *prints* de tela, que dificultam a visualização.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os pacotes estão certos, mas desatualizados. Abra o Package Manager Console (View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console) e digite o seguinte:

```
PM> Update-Package
```

Comment: Agora deu certo, parou aqueles erros depois que atualizei, porém outros erros ocorreram. ;(

Comment: Possivelmente seu projeto está **bem** desconfigurado. Edite novamente sua pergunta (desta vez sem apagar o que foi colocado antes) colocando estes novos erros.

Comment: Com certeza está bem desconfigurado, no começo creio que deve ser normal isso. Agora deu esse erro : **The navigation property 'Roles' declared on type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser`4[System.String,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole,Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim]' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities.**

Comment: Agora não é mais erro de configuração. É algum código que você alterou e que está errado. Seria melhor abrir outra pergunta detalhando como está seu arquivo `IdentityModels.cs`.

Comment: A blz então. Vou ver se consigo identificar aqui e qualquer dúvida abro outra pergunta. Obrigado pela ajuda.